# Suspend/Pause process when out of space and resume when gaining space back

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 10 how do I make auto suspension of processes when C: is running out of space and resume when gaining the space back?

Comment: You don't. Windows requires disk space.

Comment: I would suggest attaching a task to the event id detailing that disk space is running out.  Event ID 2013 I believe, do you see it?  Maybe search for "DiskSpaceThreshold" and "LowDiskSpaceMinimum" also.  At this point, you can run a script to suspend the process(es) you need to using a tool such as pssuspend https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend